# What are those brown scars in the eyes?

Tags: human-anatomy, eyes, medicine, human-eye

I have recently realised that one of my friends had brown scars or marks inside his eyes. He says that he doesn't know what they are and has been there since young. What could this possibly be ? Are those parasites ?[image]
[image]

Comment: Do you mean the lines in the white part of the eye ? Because that are blood vessels

Comment: Yeah, but why are they brown

Comment: The photo quality is bad but they are actually not how one would expect blood vessels to look like. Or it it just natural?

Comment: The photo is not of sufficient quality to allow for even an educated guess. Sorry. It's interesting, though. I'm a doc and I've never seen anything quite like it. If you could get a really good picture, I'll do some research.

Comment: @JM97 - That's the iris! You can't even see the pupil in that photograph. Are you sure you don't want to update your profile?

Comment: humans do make mistake.

Comment: one can see two lines from iris rim into sclera.

Comment: The image is not clear, but it is possible to have essentially "freckles" on the sclera. Just like on the skin, these can be harmless or not, but judging here gets into personal medical questions which we do not allow.

Comment: @BryanKrause - Those aren't typical pigment deposition. I'm very interested in what they might be.

Comment: @anongoodnurse  I have found a clearer picture.